# Why does my code throw up an extremely odd error code?

Tags: python, edx

I am doing Georgia Tech's CS1301xII lately. However, this question's error message is just strange

```
mystery_list = ["Taylor Swift", "Twenty Two", "Georgia Tech"]

#You may modify the lines of code above, but don't move them!
#When you Submit your code, we'll change these lines to
#assign different values to the variables.

#Above is a list of strings. Don't worry if this syntax is a
#little unfamiliar, we'll talk you through it and then cover
#it more in chapter 4.3.
#
#Write some code that will count the number of instances of
#the letter 't' in the list of strings. Count both capital
#'T' and lower-case 't'. Then, print the number of instances
#of the letter 't'.
#
#For example, with the list declared above, you would print
#6: two in the first string, three in the second, one in the
#third.
#
#Because we haven't used lists very extensively, we've
#gotten you started. The loop below will iterate through each
#string in the list. Next, you want to iterate through each
#letter in the current string, check if it's a t, and
#increment a counter if so.


#You'll want to add some code before the loop here.
counter = 0
listnum = 0
listletter = 0
for string in mystery_list:
   while listnum <= len(mystery_list):
       if mystery_list[listnum][listletter] == "T" or mystery_list[listnum][listletter] == "t":
           listletter += 1
       if listletter > len(mystery_list[listnum]):
           listletter = 0
           listnum += 1
```

This is the error message:

> ../resource/scripts/run.sh: line 1:   669 Killed                  python3 $VOC_SELECTED_FILE
>   Command exited with non-zero status 137

If it were a usual error like syntax or division by zero or pretty much every single error, it would give me the non-zero status 1.
So my questions are:
1. How do I fix my code
2. What does this error message even mean???

Comment: Does it take like 30 seconds or some other seemingly fixed time for that error to appear? Then it probably means that the server is killing the script because it’s running for too long, probably because you have an infinite loop.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It was an infinite loop. It was taking forever

Comment: But how should I fix it?

Comment: Error codes are not completely standard but 137 usually means out of memory. Your infinite loop ate it all up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an infinite loop in your code. listnum is always 0 causing Infinite while loop. So the server is terminating your script giving the weird error.

Here is a simple solution:

```
mystery_list = ["Taylor Swift", "Twenty Two", "Georgia Tech"]
counter = 0
for string in mystery_list:
    counter+=string.lower().count("t")
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited on your code.

```
mystery_list = ["Taylor Swift", "Twenty Two", "Georgia Tech"]
counter = 0
listnum = 0
listletter = 0
for string in mystery_list:
    while listnum < len(mystery_list):
        print('Letter:',mystery_list[listnum][listletter],'sTRING: ',mystery_list[listnum])
        if mystery_list[listnum][listletter] == "T" or mystery_list[listnum][listletter] == "t":
            counter += 1 # increment counter only if T matches
        listletter +=1  # iterete forworward no matter what
        if listletter >= len(mystery_list[listnum]):
            listletter = 0
            listnum += 1
```

Changes:

1. you forgot to increment `counter`, instead incremented iterator variable.
2. `listletter` reset condition must be `>=` as index starts from 0.